# IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I have implemented a WCF service for connecting c# project with SAP. 
But I receive the following error when I try to start the service. The error is as follows

The content type text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml"). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 442 bytes of the response were:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <soap:Fault>
            <faultcode> soap:Server </faultcode>
            <faultstring xml:lang="en"> RABAX occurred on server side </faultstring>
            <detail>
                <sap:Rabax xmlns:sap="http://www.sap.com/webas/710/soap/runtime/abap/fault/generic">
                    <SYDATUM>20170904</SYDATUM>
                    <SYUZEIT>152028</SYUZEIT>
                    <ERRORCODE>SYNTAX_ERROR</ERRORCODE>
                </sap:Rabax>
            </detail>
        </soap:Fault>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The following is my IIS config file for the WCF Service.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5" />
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="CustomBehavior">
          <clientCredentials>
            <httpDigest impersonationLevel="None" />
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="CustomBinding_HTTP">
          <binaryMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="64" maxSessionSize="2147483647">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="300" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          </binaryMessageEncoding>
          <httpTransport manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" allowCookies="false" authenticationScheme="Anonymous" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" decompressionEnabled="true" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" keepAliveEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="2147483647" proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous" realm="" transferMode="Buffered" unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false" useDefaultWebProxy="true" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="bindingBAPI" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:05:00">
          <mtomMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11"></mtomMessageEncoding>
          <httpTransport authenticationScheme="Basic" realm="SAP NetWeaver Application Server[SC3/900]"></httpTransport>
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="my end point address" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="bindingBAPI" contract="ServiceReferenceBAPI.z_bedmanagement" name="BAPIEndpoint" />
    </client>
    <services>
      <service name="Cerner.BM.Outbound.Service.BM_OutboundService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding_HTTP" name="BM_OutboundService" contract="Cerner.BM.Outbound.Service.IBM_OutboundService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>

  <!-- Client and institution value for successful BAPI Connection. -->
  <appSettings>

    <add key="BAPI_Client" value="" />
    <add key="BAPI_Institution" value="" />
    <add key="BAPI_UserName" value=""/> 
    <add key="BAPI_Password" value=""/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: do you have WCF activation feature enabled on the server? look at  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4b72d695-5790-4615-99cd-4e331d7e864d/wcf-returning-the-content-type-texthtml-of-the-response-message-does-not-match-the-content-type-of?forum=wcf

Comment: Ya. I have wcf activation feature enabled.

Comment: did you try basic http? does that work?

Comment: I am using custom binding. I have tried basichttp and it doesnt work. have changed both the server and client side as well.

Comment: in that case, I would recommend starting with a basic hello world example and then add methods to it that you need. get a minimal working set and build on it